# Convert PHP datetime to MySQL RFC-822 valid Date-Time for RSS Feed

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I want to add a date/time, created in PHP, to MySQL that is valid in a RSS Feed.

I'm using in PHP

```
$d = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s T', time() );
$mysqldate = gmdate(DATE_RSS, strtotime($d));
```

inserting that into a DATETIME field in my database

But it saves it in this format `Wed, 02 Oct 2002 08:00:00`

and it need to be in this format to be RFC-822 valid `Wed, 02 Oct 2002 08:00:00 EST`

Comment: You're confusing data with the display of that data. MySQL is not saving in any format. The actual data it saves for a datetime is a packed integer, but that's irrelevant. What you want is to display that data in a specific format, which you do in your application after you retrieve the data from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DATE_RFC822` instead of `DATE_RSS`

Comment: It now doesnt save the date/time properly in MySQL, it saves it as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: @daidai As other people have pointed out you should do this formatting when you retrieve the data from MySQL to use in the RSS feed, not when inserting into MySQL.

Comment: MySQL expects dates to be in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. It's somewhat flexible, but it won't accept an RSS/RFC822 formatted date

Answer (score 4):

Why are you converting a php date time to a string, then converting that string back into a datetime object again? that's a serious waste of cpu cycles. why not simply do

```
$mysqldate = gmdate(DATE_RSS, time())?
```

as well, gmdate generates a UTC timestamp, for which there is no timezone - it's always GMT+0

Comment: You can omit the time() argument too.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is very simple just use this format:

```
<pubDate>'.date('r', strtotime($rss_row['your_date_field'])).'</pubDate>
```

The original echo is:

```
echo date('r', strtotime($my_date));
```

This turns the datetime from inside our MySQL table which is formatted like: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and turns it into a UNIX string that represents the same date.

Once we do that to our date, we have the date() function’s many wonders at our disposal.  Going into those many wonders is more than I’ll get into here, but I’ve posted about it here.

In this particular case, adding the ‘r’ parameter to the date() function does all the work of reformatting our UNIX string into our RSS feed date format.

It’s that easy.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

When saving something into a MySQL DATETIME field, you can not specify the format. DATETIMEs are stored in an internal format that is only concerned with the **time value**, not with the formatting. You will always have to format the date the way you need it **after** (or while) retrieving it from the database:

```
date(DATE_RSS, strtotime($dateFromDatabase));
```

To insert a date into the database you just need to provide it in a format MySQL understands, it will then be converted to said internal format and the formatting will be lost:

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO `foo` (`date`) VALUES('%s')", date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date('r', strtotime($object->pubDate))
```

-works nice

Answer (score 0):

Actually DATETIME fields don't save any information about the timezone (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

So you need to append the timezone AFTER fetching the date from the database.